# Showing a point is parallel to another point

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Suppose A and B are not equal to 0. Consider the line $l$ whose cartesian equation is $Ax+By+D = 0$. Suppose $P_0 = (x_0,y_0)$ does not lie on $l$.  Let $n = (A,B)$. Let $Q_x = (x, \frac{-A}{B} - \frac{D}{B})$ be a point on $l$. For what value of $x$ is vector $P_0Q_x$ paralell to $n$?

Now as far as I know two vectors are paralell if on is the scalar multiple of the other. But going about it with that approach is not yielding me any success. I would've thought I could do something along the lines of $v = \lambda w$ but I don't think I want to involve the $\lambda$ into it. The solution is suppose to be 
$$x = \frac{B^2x_0 - ABy_0 - AD}{A^2+B^2}$$

What simple thing am I not doing?

Comment: point is parallel to a point...

Answer (score 1):

Let $Q=(x,y)$ be a point on $l$, so $y=-\frac{Ax+D}{B}$.

If $\vec{P_0Q}$ is parallel to $n$, then $\langle x-x_0, y-y_0\rangle=k\langle A,B\rangle$ for some constant $k$,

so $\frac{x-x_0}{A}=\frac{y-y_0}{B}\implies B(x-x_0)=A(y-y_0)=A(-\frac{Ax+D}{B}-y_0)$.

Multiplying by $-B$ gives $B^2(x_0-x)=A(Ax+D+By_0)$, so now solve for x.

Comment: Why did you set $\frac{x-x_0}{A}=\frac{y-y_0}{B}$? Everything else makes sense

Comment: Since $x-x_0=kA$ and $y-y_0=kB$, both fractions equal K.

Comment: makes sense. Thanks.